# Dump PSOBJECTs into an Excel table

Tags: excel, csv, powershell

I've got the following collection containing the following objects:

```
PS C:\blabla> $CSVText.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array



PS C:\blabla> $CSVText[0].gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    PSCustomObject                           System.Object
```

and I would like to dump that collection of PSOBJECTs into an xlsx file directly instead of using `$CSVText | Export-CSV` etc. and then convert the CSV file to an Excel Spreadsheet.

I am looking for a direct way to do it, from OBJECT to Excel, without any transiting and temporary CSV file involved. Is that possible?

Comment: If you do not wish to install a module, to me, the easiest way remains `PSObject` > export as CSV > open with Excel > save as Excel file ^_^.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PowerShell: Generate Real Excel XLSX Files without Excel](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19601.powershell-generate-real-excel-xlsx-files-without-excel.aspx)

also

[Export-XLSX PowerShell generate real Excel XLSX files without Excel and COM](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Export-XLSX-PowerShell-f2f0c035)

For Powershell v5:

```
Find-Module *excel*

Version    Name                                Repository           Description
-------    ----                                ----------           -----------
0.5.9      ExcelPSLib                          PSGallery            ExcelPSLib is a PowerShell Module that allows cr...
1.90       ImportExcel                         PSGallery            PowerShell module to import/export Excel spreads...
1.0        PSExcel                             PSGallery            Work with Excel without Excel
```

or at the gallery's site:

[PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages?q=excel)

note that the modules at the gallery might work with lower versions, it's just the "Find-Module" cmdlet that requires PowerShellv5

one more link:

[Use ACE Drivers and PowerShell to Talk to Access and Excel](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/05/04/use-ace-drivers-and-powershell-to-talk-to-access-and-excel.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jacqueline. Good to know when I'll run v5. I am running v4 at the moment. $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
4      0      -1     -1

Comment: the PowerShellGet Module /which exports the Find-Module thingie/ is one of the main new features, if not the main, in v5. plus the AWESOME PSReadlineLine and Pester are included in win 10 -- no idea if they also come with the v5 download